# faster way to select an element, using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know if there's a faster way to select this:

```
document.getElementById('container')
        .getElementsByTagName('p')[0]
        .getElementsByTagName('strong')[1]
        .innerText
```

The structure is:

```
<div id='container'>
   <p>
      <strong></strong>
      <strong> what I would like to get</strong>
   </p>
   <div id='moredivs'>
   </div>
   <div id='moredivs'>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Faster"? Do you mean with less code? If that's the HTML, and there's no chance it'll change, you can use a `querySelector` (I doubt it's *faster*, but I don't know that).

Answer (score 4):

Faster, no - more elegantly, yes:

FIRST you need valid HTML:

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector("#container > p > strong:last-child").textContent
);
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <p>
    <strong></strong>
    <strong>Text I'd like to get</strong>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a handy trick that I use often. It *looks* a lot like jQuery, but it isn't.

```
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const it = $('container').innerText
```

or

```
const $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
const it = $$('#container p')[0].getElementsByTagName('strong')[1].innerText
```

Not exactly jQuery, but somewhat less typing than without - and reuseable throughout the javascript file.

*And, of course, [mplugian's worthy answer (this answer thread)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64738700/1447509) can also be incorporated into this handy shorthand.*

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const txt = $('#container > p:first-of-type > strong:nth-child(2)').innerText
console.log(txt);
```

```html
<div id='container'>
   <p>
      <strong></strong>
      <strong> what I would like to get</strong>
   </p>
   <div id='moredivs'>
   </div>
   <div id='moredivs'>
   </div>
</div>
```

#### Reference:

https://dev.to/mrahmadawais/use-instead-of-document-queryselector-all-in-javascript-without-jquery-3ef1

Comment: never thought of using it that way, learn something every day, cheers @cssphus :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id='container'>
  <p>
    <strong></strong>
    <strong id='thisText'> what I would like to get</strong>
  </p>
<div id='moredivs1'> //classes are reusable, ids "aren't"
</div>
<div id='moredivs2'>
</div>
</div>
```

with:

```
document.querySelector('#thisText').innerText
```

This is what I use most often